# If you only ate fruits, vegetables or smoothies would you be able to skip drinking water?

Tags: human-biology, zoology, botany, physiology, human-physiology

If you only ate fruits, vegetables or smoothies would you be able to skip drinking water?

I do not see some animals (like squirrels) drinking water daily (doesn't mean they don't have a water source) so I am wondering if that's they case are they getting water from what they eat and can we as humans can go without water.

**1st Researched Question**:
https://www.livestrong.com/article/555187-can-you-drink-smoothies-in-place-of-fruits-vegetables/

Excerpt:

> Fresh fruits and vegetables are considered low-calorie, energy-dense
> foods. That means the food contains few calories in a high volume of
> food. They tend to be high in water – dried fruits such as raisins are
> an exception – high in fiber, high in volume and low in fat. The high
> volume and fiber help you to feel full. A smoothie, in contrast, may
> or may not be high in water, depending on how much fluid it contains.
> Most importantly, a smoothie may have little fiber or the fiber it
> does contain may have been chopped into tiny fragments by the
> manufacturing process.

**Summary:**
Fruits and veggies contain water but smoothies do not. No answer if can be a replacement for drinking water.

**2nd Researched Question:**
Can you live just on smoothies and juicing?
https://www.quora.com/Can-you-live-just-on-smoothies-and-juicing

**Summary:**
Some say people can survive eating fruits and vegetables but do not specifically if humans can survive without water.

**3rd Researched Question:**
What would happen if I drank only a smoothie everyday for a month?
https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-I-drank-only-a-smoothie-everyday-for-a-month

**Quote:**

> Without diving all the way into Maslow’s Hierarchy of human needs, we
> can pretty easily prioritize the elements of our diet according to
> urgency and importance. The order will be something like:
>
> - Water
> - Energy
> - Proteins and lipids
> - Vitamins and minerals
>
> Nobody will argue with the first one. A single smoothie would be harshly restrict fluid intake. Ideally a mid-sized person should have 2.5 liters of water each day. Estimates vary on the minimum required to maintain
> life, but some sources estimate it to be just over 1 liter per day. If
> it were a very large smoothie made with large amounts of either juice
> or water, you might be ok here.

FYI This is not information for me but information in general. Some animals in nature seem to get by without drinking water but eating fruit. Would it be safe for a human do the same? We found out a human survived by drinking sea water (although it caused other issues). Also, I'm not advocating for it but I'm wondering if it causes issues.

Comment: What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: @MattDMo I did not find any specific answers online regarding this question. I have added my notes for what I did find.

Comment: That looks a lot better. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Is there anyway to reopen this? It is not personal medical quesitons. It's general. It's an in general question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for voting this down! I didn't want to learn anything new anyway! Only 8 downvotes?

Comment: Note: this question is being [discussed on Meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4166/whats-wrong-with-this-question-that-was-edited-to-include-research).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good number of vegetables and fruits [have](https://www.bupa.co.uk/newsroom/ourviews/ten-water-rich-foods-hydration.) >90% water contents; this includes cucumber, watermelon, etc. Even oranges, broccoli etc. have >80%. So it would not be hard to have enough water intake if the veggie/fruit/smoothie diet is not restricted to particular fruits or veggies.

Slightly less detailed, but more reliable [source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2908954/table/T1/) agrees:

[image]